# Signal node.js express server from client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Problem**

A user (client) is paid 1 cent to watch a 30 second advertisement. If the user closes the browser window/tab before the 30 seconds, he should not be credited.

**Server (node.js)**

```
res.render('ad', ...);           // render the advertisement
await wait(30);                  // wait 30 seconds
// if (client closed the window) {
//     return;
// }
await creditUser(user.id, 0.01); // pay him 1 cent
```

How should I signal the server, from the client, that the window was closed?

I thought about sending an HTTP request from the client once the time is over that would credit the user, but that seems unsafe because, if someone knows the route, they can credit themselves indefinitely.

Comment: That `await` won't work there, when you are done at the server and you sent the response (`res.render`) you are finished at the server. But yes, you can send the http request from the client, if the request contains a unique uid and you allow a single uid to be sent only once and you'd accept only uids that were issued previously, no one would be able to credit themselves.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I started thinking that too - to make some sort of verification on that new HTTP request. Thank you.

Comment: "*if someone knows the route, they can credit themselves indefinitely.*" - make the route accept a token that is accessible only through the render-ad endpoint. And verify that the crediting endpoint is called within the expected timeframe. And rate-limit it. But those only are the default anti-fraud measures that simply raise the bar above trivial. You can **never** force a remote user to actually watch a video and not just simulate it.